# Overlapping file names in WIX

Tags: file, wix, windows-installer

I am facing a strange problem. My application has 2 folders. They act as 2 features (They are independent modules). Both folders have a file log4j.xml with different configurations.

To create a installer I run heat and candle on both folders and then light them to create an MSI. After installation I see that log4j.xml is same in both the folders. The log4j.xml of the 1st folder is copied to both folders.

Is this an issue or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: have you looked at the generated wxs files? Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813880/wix-harvest-same-component-file-id-when-files-are-in-different-folders

Comment: yes..... I have two wxs as a result of harvested directories and one static (product.wxs) where those harvested directories are being referenced. The files  log4j.xml in both directories have unique component and file guids in both harvested directory's wxs

Comment: Could you include the harvesting code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I have used three approaches to address this issue in the past:
My Preference:
Restructure the input area (if necessary using MSBuild Copy task or scripts) so that there is a single folder tree (which may reflect how you plan to have the files on the target system).  The point of this is to call heat once on a folder tree which has the two sub folders.  When there are files of the same name in different subfolders, heat automatically adjusts the related file/component ids.

Alternative:
It sounds like you are using -suid.  Not using it will create unique ids.

Alternative #2:
Create a transform to rename the Ids related to one of the similar files.